# Creating table without problem of exceeding page

Tags: tables, longtable

I would like to create a table like this, but the first row is too long and exceeded the width of page.
How can I create and fix this problem in latex?
[image]

Comment: Assuming your 3 columns all are `l` (or `c` or `r`), you probably want either the `p` / `m` / `b` paragraph-like styles for the last one or a flexible-width one like `X`. The latter is often combined with fixed-width tabulars. [Read up](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) on the `tabularx`, `tabu` and `ctable` packages. Similar questions must have been asked here dozens of times. Also, show your code next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest to start is use of `tabular` with `multirow`. Here the third column expands up to `0.8\textwidth`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow,array,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.8\textwidth}}


\begin{tabular}{cc|M}\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{x} & $x_1$&\lipsum[1]\\
                   & $x_2$&xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
                   & $x_3$& xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\                    
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce space between all cols(`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1 cm}`):

```
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1 cm}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cccccccccc}
  \hline
  x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x\\
  %...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

or set [hspace in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69210/hspace-in-tabular)